# Triggering an alarm at a specific time every day by using setExact()

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to trigger an alarm once at a specific time everyday. But like all others I am using `setExact()` instead of `setRepeating()`. Alarm is firing at the correct time. But once it fires it keeps on repeating itself after every 5sec. How can I trigger it only once in a day at a specific time? Here is my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Observer {

    private AlarmManager alarmManager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BroadcastObserver.getInstance().addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Alarm set through observer");
        cancelAlarm();
        setAlarm();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!checkAlarm()) {
            setAlarm();
        }

    }

    public void setAlarm() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(MyReceiver.ACTION_RECEIVER);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

    private boolean checkAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(MyReceiver.ACTION_RECEIVER);
        boolean isSet = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null;
        Log.e("MainActivity", isSet + " :Alarm is set");
        return isSet;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        cancelAlarm();
    }

    private void cancelAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(MyReceiver.ACTION_RECEIVER);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1001, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        if (pendingIntent != null) {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            pendingIntent.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ACTION_RECEIVER = "Receiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "triggered");
        BroadcastObserver.getInstance().updateValue(intent);
    }
}
```

BroadcastObserver:

```
public class BroadcastObserver extends Observable {
    private static BroadcastObserver instance = new BroadcastObserver();

    public static BroadcastObserver getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    private BroadcastObserver(){}

    public void updateValue(Object data) {
        synchronized (this) {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you cancel and set the alarm every day? should you use setRepeating to repeat every day?

Comment: `setRepeating()` is more towards optimization and it may trigger anytime after the specific is reached. So its not so exact in trigger the alarm. This is what I have seen in books.

Comment: Post the code of `BroadcastObserver` please.

Comment: Updated. @earthw0rmjim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> once it fires it keeps on repeating itself after every 5 sec

You are setting an alarm for 14:13 for a given day. When the alarm fires the `Observer` is notified and it sets the exact **same** alarm (for 14:13).

At this point we're past 14:13, so the alarm will fire immediately, notifying the `Observer` again, resulting in an infinite loop of the above steps.

The simplest solution might be to check the time when setting the alarm and if it's in the past, then add a day to it:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 13);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
}
```

To avoid memory leaks you need to remove the `Observer` when appropriate:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    BroadcastObserver.getInstance().deleteObserver(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Also, cancelling the alarm in `update()` is redundant. This is not a repeating alarm, so it makes no sense to cancel it after it fired.